# Vector Algebra - Prove Line Cuts Diagonal at trisection.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Prove that in the parallelogram OABC the line drawn from O to the mid-point of AB cuts AC at the point of trisection of AC that is nearer to A.

[image]

Here is my attempt:

We can see that $CA=CO +OA= a - b$

$OT = OC + CT$

$CT = pCA = p(a-b)$, where p is a scalar

$therefore, OT=OC + CT=b + pa - pb$ --- (1)

$TA = qCA = q(a-b) = qa-qb$ --- (2), where q is a scalar

We can see that:
$OA=OT+TA$

$a = (b + pa - pb) + (qa - qb)$

This rearranges to:
$a(1-p+q)=b(1-p-q)$

Since these are non-parallel vectors, $1-p+q=0$ and $1-p-q=0$

Solving the simultaneous equation gives us:

$p=0,  q=1$

But this is wrong, since the rations of CA are clearly not this. I am not sure why this method does not work, it does seem to make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What you wrote is basically correct but, going from $a = (b + pa - pb) + (qa - qb)$, you got $a(1-p\color{red}{+q})=b(1-p-q)$, but it should be $a(1-p\color{red}{-q})=b(1-p-q)$ instead, i.e., you used a "$+q$" instead of a "$-q$". This then leads to $1-p-q=0\;\;\to\;\;p+q=1$. It makes sense since $p$ and $q$ are the fractions of $CA$ that correspond to $CT$ and $TA$, respectively. Unfortunately, this then becomes $0 = 0$, so you can't really go much further using that line of reasoning.

Comment: FYI, one minor thing, although this might just be a typo, but from $1-p+q=0$ and $1-p-q=0$, you should get $p=1, q=0$ instead of $p=0, q=1$.

Comment: Instead of letting T cut $CA$ in the ratio $p:q$ with $p+q = 1$, you should let $T$ cut CA in the ratio $p:1$ and let $T$ cut $OM$ in the ratio $q:1$. Can you set up those equations and solve for $OT$? Hence, show that $ p = 2$, hence it's a trisection.

Comment: Notice that $AM:OC=2:1$. Because $\triangle TAM$ is similar to $\triangle TCO$, $TC:AT=2:1$ as well, in other words, $T$ lies at the point of trisection of $AC$

Answer (score 0):

I solved it another way as well:

[image]

I realized that we can figure out $OT$ and $TC$ and equate it to $OC$.

Finding OT:

$$OM =OA+AM=OA+\frac{1}{2}AB=OA+\frac{1}{2}OC=\textbf{b}+\frac{1}{2}\textbf{a}$$
$$OT=p(OM)$$ where p is a scalar.
$$OT=p(\textbf{b}+\frac{1}{2}\textbf{a})$$

Finding OC:
$$AC=AO+OC=\textbf{-b}+\textbf{a}=\textbf{a}-\textbf{b}$$
$$TC = q(AC)$$
Where q is a scalar.
$$TC = q(\textbf{a}-\textbf{b})$$

We know $OC = \textbf{a}$ and $OC = OT + TC$:

$$OC = OT + TC$$
$$\textbf{a}=p(\textbf{b}+\frac{1}{2}\textbf{a}) + q(\textbf{a}-\textbf{b})$$
$$\textbf{a}(1-\frac{p}{2}-q)=\textbf{b}(p+q)$$

Since these are non-parallel vectors:
$$1-\frac{p}{2}-q=0, p+q=0$$

Solving simultaneously gives us:
$$q=\frac{2}{3}, p=\frac{2}{3}$$

Since $TC=qA=\frac{2}{3}AC, AT=\frac{1}{3}AC$ (ANS)

Comment: Good work. However, you went from $\textbf{a}=p(\textbf{b}+\frac{1}{2}\textbf{a}) + q(\textbf{a}-\textbf{b})$ to $\textbf{a}(1-\frac{p}{2}-q)=\textbf{b}(p\color{red}{+}q)$, but it should be $\textbf{a}(1-\frac{p}{2}-q)=\textbf{b}(p\color{red}{-}q)$ instead. The second equation then becomes $p-q=0\;\;\to\;\;p=q$. Your first equation then gives that $1-\frac{q}{2}-q=0\;\;\to\;\;1=\frac{3q}{2}\;\;\to\;\;q=\frac{2}{3}$, with $p=\frac{2}{3}$ as well.